# How to link models which have many to many relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am kinda new to RoR, need some help.

I have 2 master models:

1. apartement
2. facility

And I have 1 table (property_facility) to link both parents table,
so an apartement can have a lot of facilities, and a facility can belong
to a lot of apartements, I tried this :

### apt model :

```
  has_many :facilities, through: :property_facilities

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :property_facilities
```

### facility model :

```
       has_many :apts, through: :property_facilities

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :property_facilities
```

### property_facility model :

```
       belongs_to :apt
      belongs_to :facility
```

Somehow I can not make it to work, it throw me an error

> No association found for name `property_facilities'. Has it been defined yet?

I am using rails 4.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take in the `associations`, the same name as the models,

**whenever a model has one-many relation-ship associations should be plural names.(eg: has_many)


For one-one associations should be singluar name.(eg: has_one, belongs_to)**

**Apt model :**

```
class Apt < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :property_facilities
    has_many :facilities, through: :property_facilities

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :property_facilities

end
```

**Facility model :**

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :property_facilities   
    has_many :apts, through: :property_facilities

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :property_facilities

end
```

**property_facility model :**

```
class PropertyFacility < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :apt

    belongs_to :facility

end
```

Comment: hi, thx for your answer, my bad.. i forgot to mention, my model name is apt.

Comment: your models look just like mine, somehow it's not working.

Comment: now whats the error? reload the console if you are trying in console.

Comment: it still throwing this error "No association found for name `property_facilities'. Has it been defined yet?"

Comment: Hey there shld be `has_many :property_facilities` in both the models apt and facility pls check the updated ans.